# Give id to html element inside Razor without using class

Tags: razor

```
@if (Model.Something != null)  
{ 
<span id="SpanID">Model.SomethingElse</span> 
}  
else  
{
<span id="SpanID">Model.SomethingElse2</span>
}
```

I am getting error. Another object on this page already uses ID 'SpanID'.
I want to accomplish this by using ID only(and not using class) because lots of other things depend on that.

Comment: I think it's ok, and you shouldn't be worried about editor's complaint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a variable and use that within your span.

```
@{
    var result = Model.Something != null ? 
        Model.SomethingElse : Model.SomethingElse2;
}

<span id="SpanID">@result</span>
```

As Alex mentioned the best way is to move this logic to the controller and populate a `ViewModel` with only the data required for the view.  This also makes more of your code testable.

Comment: This is what exactly I want. Thanks a lot. 
With this method, I don't have to use Viewdata or Class. 
This really saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite it:

```
@{
    if (Model.Something != null) {
        ViewData["whatever"] = Model.SomethingElse;
    }
    else {
        ViewData["whatever"] = Model.SomethingElse2;
    }
}

<span id="SpanID">@ViewData["whatever"]</span>
```

Or use a ViewModel, moving the check from the View to the Controller (where it belongs, methinks).

Comment: This works ... But I want to have ID over there , so that I can manipulate those spans even after Page Loads.
But I think , whatever I want to accomplish is against HTML Basics and there is no way around other than Class/or your method. 
Thanks !