# Get rid of Visual Studio warning which in reality would never happen

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2012

I have a `<span>` which the value is depended upon a condition:

```
@{
      if(Session["Status1"]!=null){
           <span id="currentStatus">Found</span>
      }
       else {
           <span id="currentStatus">Not Found</span>
        }
  }
```

As you can see because of the conditional checking, there will never be 2 `<span>` with the same id `currentStatus`. However, Visual Studio 2012 (not Community nor Express) is giving me a warning:

> Another object on this page already uses ID currentStatus.

How do I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by [this feedback](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/629676/mvc3-when-using-if-else-warning-the-id-has-the-same-one), this behavior is *by design*.

> Unfortunately the **HTML validator is not designed to determine if
>   blocks are being conditionally emitted due to server code**. Therefore,
>   it only sees the HTML, not the if statement, and thinks there are two
>   elements with the same ID.

To get rid of this warning completely, you can create a variable and use it within single `span` element:

```
@{
    string status = (Session["Status1"] != null) ? "Found" : "Not Found";
}

<span id="currentStatus">@status</span>
```

Or put conditional check in controller action method instead and assign the result to a viewmodel string property:

```
// Model
public class ViewModel
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

// Controller
public ActionResult ActionName()
{
    var model = new ViewModel();
    model.Status = (Session["Status1"] != null) ? "Found" : "Not Found";
    return View(model);
}

// View
@model ViewModel
<span id="currentStatus">@Model.Status</span>
```

NB: Unfortunately I can't see the warning in VS 2013 and above, hence it possibly only affects certain version of MVC (e.g. MVC 3).

Similar issue:

[Give id to html element inside Razor without using class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385424/give-id-to-html-element-inside-razor-without-using-class)